# Changing the size of static array

Tags: c++, c

We have declared an array like below in our code.
array is to be handled on the stack itself.
we are not allocating any memory on heap with `malloc` or `new`

```
char a[20000];
```

Now there is need for us to change it to `1800000(180kb)` instead of `20kb`.
like below:

```
char a[1800000];
```

we are just filling the array with some data.
is this a valid thing to do?

what are the problems that we might face?
I am just concerned that the value seems to be too big.
are there any better ways to bypass this need?

I am working on solaris unix platform.

Comment: Do you need to support 16-bit platforms?

Comment: NOTE: 1,800,000 bytes is about 1.7 MB, not 180 KB

Comment: Yeah you are right..i just rounded it off but thats not the concern overe here :)

Comment: i'd define the size as `char a[ 1024 * 1024 * 20 ] /* <- 20 kbytes */`, it's more readble and less error-prone in the case you are going to change the size.

Comment: You say "static array here i mean is array is to be handled on the stack itself". That's not what "static" means; static objects are persistent, so cannot be on the stack. Do you actually mean "automatic"?

Comment: Size does matter when deciding whether it's reasonable to use the stack, so you need to clarify whether it's 180 KB or 1.7 MB.  For example, on Windows, 180KB would be perfectly reasonable; however, 1.7 MB would not work (without changing compiler settings) because the default stack size is 1MB.

Comment: use `realloc` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/ I propose closing the question.

Answer (score 5):

Significant increases in size of variables declared such as this can impact the stack.  I would suggest to replace this with a `std::vector`, which will create the bulk of memory needed from the heap.  This is tagged `C++` after all.

Comment: `static` would unlikely to be implemented on the stack.

Comment: While the question implies that, its not clear from the posted code that is the case.  If this were declared in function local scope there could be consequences, if it would even compile.

Comment: Any arguments against moving to `std::vector` though?  I see this as a better alternative than a raw pointer using `malloc/new` since it memory management is handled by the `vector`

Comment: Would love to understand the downvote.  If you've ever worked with teams that use English as a second language you would know that the question could easily be asking about a non-dynamic segment with function local scope.

Comment: In fact the question clearly states "by static array I mean the array is to be handled on the stack itself"

Comment: @Chad you are correct. Looks like the question was about non-dynamic segment with function local scope.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to use std::vector.

Answer (score 2):

Is this array really static? Because there is no `static` keyword.

Whatever, creating such a big array on the stack is not something you really should do. Depending on the compiler your programm could just crash and depending on the platform and OS it can crash, too.

If you have to create such a big array you should do it with `malloc()` in C or `new` in C++:

```
char *array = malloc(1800000 * sizeof(*array));
```

This is much more portable and more safe. Also, you cannot resize data on the stack. So, use the heap.

HTH,
 CK

Comment: This is why I asked for the keyword „static.” But the static storage is often limited, too, while the heap is only limited by the RAM. Use the heap, Luke! :-)

Comment: The OP is likely referring to static storage duration, which every variable allocated at file scope will get.

Answer (score 2):

If you actually mean "static", and this is for a reasonably modern platform, then there's no problem with static objects of that size. On a 32-bit platform, you'll start to have difficulties when you get into the low gigabytes; on 64-bit platforms, the only limit is the amount of storage capacity available.

However, you also say this is on the stack, implying that it's automatic rather than static. This could be a problem, especially in a multi-threaded program, since the stack has a fixed size. You should therefore avoid putting large objects on the stack; make them static if that's appropriate, or dynamic otherwise - create it with `malloc` in C, and use a `std::vector<char>` in C++.

In the unlikely event that you need to support 8- or 16-bit platforms, you may find that it's difficult or impossible to create objects larger than 64kb. In this case, you might want to break it up into smaller pieces (assuming you have more than 64kb of RAM; otherwise, saving and loading pages from tapes or diskettes is possible, but very slow).

Answer (score 1):

Use Malloc or new for sizes in this range.  The heap, in general, will be better suited for larger allocations.  Easier to resize as well.  This is especially true if your allocations are happening within a function scope, which would place it on the stack.  If these are globals, not quite as bad.  But still, I'd stick with a heap allocation if possible.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why the heap might be better than a data segment?

Comment: Resize is not required as we are sure that 1.8mb is enough

Comment: @MikeSeymour The question, lacking any `static` keyword even states specifically that the array "will be handled on the stack itself".  So,yes the heap is more appropriate for segments of   this size.

Comment: @Chad: Sorry, I just read the word "static" and not "handled by the stack itself". The correct answer rather depends on what the OP means by "static" and "the stack".

Answer (score 1):

To clarify some basic concepts:

There is the keyword static, and there is static storage duration, which means that the variable will persist throughout the execution of the program, and that there will only be one instance of the variable allocated. Objects with static storage duration are stored in a specific segment in RAM, often referred to as [.bss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss). All variables declared as static or at file scope (globals) have static storage duration. Variables with static storage duration are guaranteed to be initialized to zero by the C/C++ standards.

The stack is a dynamic part of the RAM where local variables and function parameters most often are allocated. Variables allocated on the stack are usually referred to as automatic, as in, let the compiler automatically handle this variable and allocate it at the most suitable location, which could be on the stack, but also in CPU registers, cache memory etc. There is a keyword in C/C++ for this called `auto` but you don't need to use it: all local variables and parameters are auto by default. Variables with automatic storage will contain garbage values unless initialized explicitly.

The heap is another dynamic part of the RAM, which is only used when you explicitly allocate variables there through malloc or `new`. The heap is what you usually refer to when talking about dynamic memory allocation (sometimes also referred to as free store management). Variables allocated dynamically will contain garbage values unless initialized explicitly.

On most computers, the static segment and the heap are only limited by the amount of RAM you have, while the stack has a fixed, limited size. On multi-tasking systems like Unix, there will be one stack per process in the computer. I am not sure how large .bss or stack Unix/Solaris allows, I suspect it will depend on how old the computer is. Older machines will likely have problems allocating 1.7MB on the stack. I don't know much about Unix machines, but I suspect that the recommendation is to allocate all such large amounts of data dynamically on the heap (that's what you would do on a PC).

Comment: Slight correction to your clarification: when you say `Objects with static storage duration are stored in a specific segment in RAM, often referred to as .bss`, I'd preface "Objects" with `Uninitialized`; initialized objects are usually placed in another segment, not .bss.  Also when you say `Variables with static storage duration are guaranteed to be initialized to zero by the C/C++ standards`, I'd recommend editing that to `Uninitialized variables`

Comment: @Dan: I take it that with "uninitialized" you refer to variables with static storage that wasn't explicitly initialized by the programmer? I'm not so sure that this is universally true for all compilers. I think I have seen some embedded ones that wouldn't make any difference between implicitly and explicitly initialized variables, but instead place them all in .bss.

Answer (score 0):

> we are just filling the array with some data. is this a valid thing to
>   do?

yes

> what are the problems that we might face?

If all data access is based off front of array, not many. If offsets are taken from end or based on some calculation involving the size there may be an issue.

> I am just concerned that the value seems to be too big. are there any
>   better ways to bypass this need?

There are better ways, but not really because of its size. [STL containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) would be a great idea. A `std::vector`(for example) can be resized during runtime for whatever your current need is.

Comment: If you are using std::vector then you are using dynamic memory, which the OP explicitly said they don't want to use, they want to allocate the array on the stack (or in a static memory segment). std::vector uses the heap.

Comment: @Lundin That's not what version 1 of the question said. And I answered the original question with stl as a suggestion.

Comment: Yeah I noticed this after posting my comment.

Answer (score 0):

On a normal program that size is irrelevant, just take images for example, they hold mbs and mbs of data, sometimes even gigs. If your program runs on modern computer, I wouldn't worry at all about the size.

You should though consider encapsulating that data inside an object that will be dynamically allocated, as you can increase the size of the data in runtime with `realloc` (if using c). If done correctly, this will also help you hide implementation details.

Comment: Stack size and executable size matter - both are much more limited than heap allocation.